# loading dlls during C# runtime

Tags: c#, dll, interop

I am trying to write a generic service for a C# application that handles loading dll(s) at runtime. It reads in a list of directories specified in a configuration file and checks those directories for the missing assembly. I am planning to use assemblyResolve event handler in C# for this purpose as described in:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Can you provide some suggestions on how should I design this and what are the potential issues with this approach? Will this work for all C# dlls and C++ interop dlls that the CLR can't find during runtime?

If there is an existing application or utility out there for this purpose, please point me to it.

thanks

Comment: Isn't MEF good for that?

Comment: it is, but this assumes a poster reading the documentation of the Tools he uses.

Answer (score 0):

[Load Assembly from Specific Directory Path](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_502.asp) it's a good sample. [Here] you can also find a discussion for how to load you assemblies.

Comment: Thanks. Does it work for interop C++ or unmanaged DLLs?

Comment: I guess it should. I've never worked with those so you'd better test it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively useing MEF (Microsoft Extensibility Framework) may also be suitable. At the end that just all starts with Google and "load Assembly dynamically" or a similar trivial query.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to a specific example if possible? thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/. Try somthing arcane such as "MEF example".